# Parse and Return Jenkins Console Output

Tags: jenkins, groovy, ansible, continuous-integration

Within Jenkins, I would like to parse the ansible playbook "Play Recap" output section for the failing hostname(s).  I want to put the information into an email or other notification.  This could also be used to fire off another Jenkins job.

I'm currently submitting an ansible-playbook as a jenkins job to deploy software across a number of systems.  I'm using a Jenkins Pipeline script, which was necessary to implement for sshagent to be applied correctly.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        ansiColor('xterm')
    }
    stages {
        stage("setup environment") {
            steps {
                deleteDir()
            } //steps
        } //stage - setup environment
        stage("clone the repo") {
            environment {
                GIT_SSH_COMMAND = "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
            } //environment
            steps {
                sshagent(['my_git']) {
                    sh "git clone ssh://git@github.com/~usr/ansible.git" 
                } //sshagent
            } //steps
        } //stage - clone the repo
        stage("run ansible playbook") {
            steps {
                sshagent (credentials: ['apps']) {
                    withEnv(['ANSIBLE_CONFIG=ansible.cfg']) {
                        dir('ansible') {
                            ansiblePlaybook(
                                becomeUser: null, 
                                colorized: true, 
                                credentialsId: 'apps',
                                disableHostKeyChecking: true,
                                forks: 50,
                                hostKeyChecking: false,
                                inventory: 'hosts', 
                                limit: 'production:&*generic', 
                                playbook: 'demo_play.yml', 
                                sudoUser: null,
                                extras: '-vvvvv'
                            ) //ansiblePlaybook
                        } //dir
                    } //withEnv
                } //sshagent
            } //steps
        } //stage - run ansible playbook
    } //stages
    post {
        failure { 
            emailext body: "Please go to ${env.BUILD_URL}/consoleText for more details.",
            recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']],
            subject: "${env.JOB_NAME}",
            to: 'our.dev.team@gmail.com',
            attachLog: true
            
            office365ConnectorSend message:"A production system appears to be unreachable.",
                status:"Failed",
                color:"f00000",
                factDefinitions: [[name: "Credentials ID", template: "apps"],
                                  [name: "Build Duration", template: "${currentBuild.durationString}"],
                                  [name: "Full Name", template: "${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}"]],
                webhookUrl:'https://outlook.office.com/webhook/[really long alphanumeric key]/IncomingWebhook/[another super-long alphanumeric key]'
        } //failure
    } //post
} //pipeline
```

There are several Jenkins plug-ins for parsing the console output, but none will let me capture and utilize text.  I have looked at [log-parser](https://plugins.jenkins.io/log-parser/) and [text finder](https://plugins.jenkins.io/text-finder/).

The only lead I have is using groovy to script this.
https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/5363/jenkins-groovy-to-parse-console-output-and-mark-build-failure

An example of "Play Recap" within the console output is:

```
PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************
some.host.name     : ok=25   changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
some.ip.address    : ok=22   changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I am trying to get either a list or a delimited string of each host that is failing.  Although, in the case of a list, I need to figure out how to send multiple notifications.

If anyone could help me with the full solution, I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Hi @cfrick There is no error that I'm receiving.  And the tools i've found don't have the capability that I'm looking forl.  I'm simply hoping someone can help me pull the information from the console output so I can use it in an email and a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few 'gotchas' that I came across as I solved this problem.

1. The only successful way I could access the output of the ansible plugin was through pulling the raw log file.  `def log = currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(100)`  In this case I only pulled the last 100 lines, as I'm only looking for the Play Recap box.  This method requires special permissions. The console log will display the error and provide a link where the functions can be allowed.
2. The ansible output should not be colorized. `colorized: false` Colorized output is quite difficult to parse.  The 'console log' doesn't show you the colorized markup, however if you look at the 'consoleText' you will see it.
3. When using regex, you will most likely have a `matcher` object which is non-serializable.  To use this in Jenkins, it may need to be placed in a function tagged `@NonCPS` which stops Jenkins from trying to serialize the object.  I had mixed results with needing this, so I don't exhaustively understand where it's required.
4. The regex statement was one of the harder parts for me.  I came up with a generic statement that could be easily modified for different scenarios e.g. failed or unreachable.  I also had more luck using the 'slashy-style' regex in groovy which places a forward slash on either end of the statement with no need for quotes of any kind.  You'll note the 'failed' portion is different `failed=([1-9]|[1-9][0-9])`, so that it only matches a statement where the failure is non-zero.

```
/([0-9a-zA-Z\.\-]+)(?=[ ]*:[ ]*ok=([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])[ ]*changed=([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])[ ]*unreachable=([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])[ ]*failed=([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]))/
```

Here's the full pipeline code that I came up with.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        ansiColor('xterm')
    }
    stages {
        stage("setup environment") {
            steps {
                deleteDir()
            } //steps
        } //stage - setup environment
        stage("clone the repo") {
            environment {
                GIT_SSH_COMMAND = "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
            } //environment
            steps {
                sshagent(['my_git']) {
                    sh "git clone ssh://git@github.com/~usr/ansible.git" 
                } //sshagent
            } //steps
        } //stage - clone the repo
        stage("run ansible playbook") {
            steps {
                sshagent (credentials: ['apps']) {
                    withEnv(['ANSIBLE_CONFIG=ansible.cfg']) {
                        dir('ansible') {
                            ansiblePlaybook(
                                becomeUser: null, 
                                colorized: false, 
                                credentialsId: 'apps',
                                disableHostKeyChecking: true,
                                forks: 50,
                                hostKeyChecking: false,
                                inventory: 'hosts', 
                                limit: 'production:&*generic', 
                                playbook: 'demo_play.yml', 
                                sudoUser: null,
                                extras: '-vvvvv'
                            ) //ansiblePlaybook
                        } //dir
                    } //withEnv
                } //sshagent
            } //steps
        } //stage - run ansible playbook
    } //stages
    post {
        failure {
            script {
                problem_hosts = get_the_hostnames()
            }
            emailext body: "${problem_hosts} has failed.  Please go to ${env.BUILD_URL}/consoleText for more details.",
            recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']],
            subject: "${env.JOB_NAME}",
            to: 'our.dev.team@gmail.com',
            attachLog: true
            
            office365ConnectorSend message:"${problem_hosts} has failed.",
                status:"Failed",
                color:"f00000",
                factDefinitions: [[name: "Credentials ID", template: "apps"],
                                  [name: "Build Duration", template: "${currentBuild.durationString}"],
                                  [name: "Full Name", template: "${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}"]],
                webhookUrl:'https://outlook.office.com/webhook/[really long alphanumeric key]/IncomingWebhook/[another super-long alphanumeric key]'
        } //failure
    } //post
} //pipeline

//@NonCPS
def get_the_hostnames() {
    // Get the last 100 lines of the log
    def log = currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(100)
    print log
    // GREP the log for the failed hostnames
    def matches = log =~ /([0-9a-zA-Z\.\-]+)(?=[ ]*:[ ]*ok=([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])[ ]*changed=([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])[ ]*unreachable=([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])[ ]*failed=([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]))/
    def hostnames = null
    // if any matches occurred
    if (matches) {
        // iterate over the matches
        for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++) {
            // if there is a name, concatenate it
            // else populate it
            if (hostnames?.trim()) {
                hostnames = hostnames + " " + matches[i]
            } else {
                hostnames = matches[i][0]
            } // if/else
        } // for
    } // if
    if (!hostnames?.trim()) {
        hostnames = "No hostnames identified."
    }
    return hostnames
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"Parse the ansible playbook 'Play Recap' output section."*

A: Use *json* callback and parse the output with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). For example

```sh
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json ansible-playbook pb.yml | jq .stats
```

Comment: jq is definitely a cool tool that I haven't seen before.  I'm not sure I can apply it within my jenkins pipeline script.  I updated my description to include those details.  Thank you very much for showing me something new!